# What is the best way to set/update association lookup field inside Doctrine entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

I have the main entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Document
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var DocumentStatus
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DocumentStatus")
     */
    private $status;
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $text;
}
```

and the lookup "enum" entity (seeding on application deploy)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DocumentStatusRepository");
 */

class DocumentStatus
{
    const DRAFT = 'draft';
    const PENDING = 'pending';
    const APPROVED = 'approved';
    const DECLINED = 'declined';
    /**
     * @var int Surrogate primary key
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string  Natural primary key (name for developers)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $key;
    /**
     * @var string Short name for users
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @var string Full decription for users
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $description;
}
```

with simple repository

```
class DocumentStatusRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneByKey($key)
    {
        return parent::findOneBy(['key' => $key]);
    }
}
```

I want to encapsulate domain logic of document lifecycle by intoducing methods like

```
public function __construct($text)
{
   $this->text = $text;
   $this->status = $something->getByKey(DocumentStatus::DRAFT);
}

public function approve()
{
    try {
        $this->doSomeDomainActions();
        $this->status = $something->getByKey(DocumentSatus::DRAFT);
    } catch (SomeDomainException($e)) {
        throw new DocumentApproveException($e);
    }
}
...
```

or

```
public function __construct($text)
{
   $this->text = $text;
   $this->status = $something->getDraftDocumentStatus()
}

public function approve()
{
    $this->status = $something->getApprovedDocumentStatus()
}
...
```

without public setters. Also I want keep Document loose coupling and testable.

I see the next ways:

- Permanent inject DocumentStatusRepository (or service that encapsulates it) into every instance by constructor on entity creation and by using public setter in postLoad subscriber
- Permanent inject DocumentStatusRepository by static Document method on application bootstrap or on loadClassMetadata
- Temporary inject DocumentStatusRepository in constructor and methods like Document::approve
- Use setStatus() method with complex logic based on $status->key value
- Encapsulate document domain logic in some DocumentManager and use Document entity like simple data storgae or DTO :(

Are there other ways? Which way is easier and more convenient to use in the long term?

Answer (score 1):

1. Using generated Identities for Document.
   Now you generate the identity on the side of the database. So you `save` Document from the domain perspective in inconsistent state.   Entity/Aggregate `should be identified`, if it has no id it shouldn't exists.
   If you really want to keep to database serials, add method to the repository which will generate id for you.
   Better way is to use uuid generator for example ramsey/uuid. 
   And `inject` the id `to the constructor`.
2. `DocumentStatus` as Value Object
   Why Document Status is Entity? It does look like a simple Value Object.
   Then you can use Embeddable annotation. So it will leave within same table in the database, no need for doing inner joins.
   DocumentStatus gets behaviour for example ->draftDocumentStatus(), which `returns NEW DocumentStatus` with draft status, so you can switch the old instance one with new one. ORM will do the rest.
3. DocumentStatusRepository
   If you really want to keep DocumentStatus as entity, which in my opinion `is wrong` you shouldn't have DocumentStatusRepository.
   Document is your aggregate root and the `only entrance` to the DocumentStatus, should be by aggregate root.
   So you will have DocumentRepository only, which will be responsible for `rebuilding` the whole aggregate and `saving` it. 
   Also you should change the mapping.
   It should have `FETCH=EAGER` type, so it will retrieve DocumentStatus with Document together.
   Secondly you should do mapping with `CASCADE=ALL` and `ORPHANREMOVAL=TRUE`.
   Otherwise, if you `remove` Document, DocumentStatus `will stay in the database`.

Comment: 1. Thanks for advice. I understand disadvantage of 'before insert' generated identifiers like MySQL AUTOINCREMENT fields.

Comment: 2. Yes, in business terms it is Value Object, but if we will using it as Embeddable then we will have 'name' and 'description' fields in each document table's record. It takes a lot of disk space and makes database denormalized.  On the other hand 'name' and 'description' serve only UI tasks now and basically we don't need them in database. But in the feature possible we will add other fields like 'apllies_from_date' and  make database constaraint for document.status_id based on document creation date and status applies from date. So we want table 'document_status' in the database anyway.

Comment: 3. Document have many-to-one association with DocumentStatus. On initial application deploy we have no documents and have four document_status. Later we will have millions  documents and same four statuses. If we remove some document we mast stay status in database. The Document is not owner of the DocumentStatus when last is Entity (not ValueObject).